# Помогите с IntelliSense (VS2022). Сбой подсистемы IntelliSense для файла ... . Просто отказывается работать и все

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, intellisense

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это все что мне показывается IDE Vusial Studio. Как найти и как решить эту проблему вообще не понятно. В микрософтах все что сделали это просто рекомендации к подсветке.
*Если надо как-то дополнить вопрос пишите в коммах.*

Comment: Стандартные советы: попробуйте не использовать пробелы и non-ASCII символы в пути к файлу, переустановите, очистите кеш.

Comment: Вопрос надо дополнить, приведя [mcve]

Comment: @user7860670 чел каким образом? У меня сбой в IDE и проблемы с настройками или нехватка модулей, а не траблы с кодом....

Comment: [mcve] нужен, чтобы этот сбой в IDE, или что у вас там происходит, могли воспроизвести читающие этот вопрос. Ну и еще его можно будет отправить как багрепорт в микрософт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все дело оказалось все таки в названии пути (как и сказал @tocic в комментах спасибо ему!).

> Стандартные советы: попробуйте не использовать пробелы и non-ASCII
> символы в пути к файлу, переустановите, очистите кеш.

Comment: IntelliSense прекрасно работает при наличии пробелов и non-ASCII символов в путях к файлам. Так что дело было не в IntelliSense